# How to check if notification is called then do not call method

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I have two methods in `viewDidLoad` of the app and I want that if the notification method is called then the other method should not be called.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(actionNotificationDataA:)
                                             name:@"reloadDataActivity"
                                           object:nil];
```

Below is the other method. I want that if the notification method is not called, then this method should be called:

```
   [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(allData:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

Otherwise, this method shouldn't be called.

Comment: in which status of your application for  notification call ? and which status of not called ? you need to take object for fixed it :)

Comment: @iPatel i am not getting you i want that if notification is called then it should not call the other method

Answer (score 0):

First one will get called only when post that notification somewhere. But the second will detach the new thread suddenly when the code runs. That may create a problem look at it.

**For an idea to your requirement:**

Keep a `BOOL` with default to `NO`.
Then in the both methods check if the `boolValue` is `NO`, then run the code only if `boolValue` is `NO` and change the `boolValue` to `YES`.

Answer (score 0):

Put `BOOL isNotifCall;` in your `.h file`.

In starting of `viewDidLoad` Method, give  `NO` to `isNotifCall`, such like,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    isNotifCall = NO;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(actionNotificationDataA:)
                                             name:@"reloadDataActivity"
                                           object:nil];

   [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(allData:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

}
```

Method of your `NSThread` *(I don't know about parameter so i take `id`)*

```
-(void)actionNotificationDataA:(id)Sender
{
  isNotifCall = YES;

  .
  .
  .
  /// your Stuuf;
}
```

Method of your notification *(I don't know about parameter so i take `id`)*

```
-(void) allData:(id)Sender
{
  if(!isNotifCall)
  {
     /// your allData method's Stuuf;

  }
}
```